# matlab: quadprog complaining functional is not symmetrical when it is

Tags: matlab, quadprog

When I am running `quadprog` with a given functional `F` matlab outputs:

```
Warning: Your Hessian is not symmetric.
Resetting H=(H+H')/2.
```

However, checking the difference between the functional and it's transpose:

```
>> max(max(abs(F-F')))

ans =

   (1,1)     7.1054e-015
```

Shows that they are in fact the same. Does `quadprog` output this warning even if the functional is close to being symmetrical by a machine error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test used for presence of antisymmetry in the quadprog source is

```
norm(H-H',inf) > eps
```

i.e. it checks if the infinity norm is greater than machine epsilon. Since

```
7.1054e-15 > eps = 2.22e-16
```

your Hessian shows up as non-symmetric.